# Should I worry about excessive data forgery from my users on Firebase?

Tags: xss, data-validation

I'm getting familiar with Firebase and the firestore database.

I have a small project relying on a certain data format. It is a simple React project with direct connexion to its firestore, so no back-end. I know this is usually a bad design, but please bear with me.

The data access has been secured with security rules so users need to be authenticated and authorized to be able to use and store their data. For the sake of this question, let's assume I did that part seemlessly.

Should I worry about users being able to hack my react front and use the public access keys to forge enormous volumes of data?

Should I worry about users being able to bypass the data format enforced by my react application and storing malformed data (or event script injections !) in my firestore collections?

This app is just a pet project so I don't care about it, but I am still wondering if I were to use this on a more critical project. My first thought is I would add a back-end to handle my firestore, if security is a major concern.

Each search I do on this subject always leads to people talking about the firestore rules, which are out of scope here.

Comment: I understand firestore rules can be used to validate data format to some extent, but it does not seem like a good practice, as it would lead to huge rules.

Comment: I have yet to look for rules that manage data volumes per user, if that is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase will not protect you against XSS. Neither you can implement it in React, because user controls the code of the React application. On the other hand, as long as data of one user are not displayed to other users, it is fine. You decide, if this is a risk for you.

Comment: Did you mean "are NOT displayed"? Thanks this is interesting for the xss part. It just leaves out the data volume issue.

Comment: Also, on that current project, only manually authorised users can handle data, so it should be pretty safe.

Comment: @Lewis: Yes, I mean "are not displayed". I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Lewis: *"only manually authorised"* - this doesn't say anything about displaying of data of one user to the other users. Depending on that, you app XSS can be problem or not.

Comment: @Lewis: *"so it should be pretty safe"* - safe against what? Against XSS? Besides XSS, there can be other problems like CORS, XSRF. You don't tell us anything if you have implemented any measures to protect against these problems.

Comment: by "manually authorised" and "pretty safe" I mean I personally know my users, which are family members. So security breaches in that situation would mean Google account compromission, which we cannot do anything against.

Comment: CORS can be handled by the firebase project so it is out of the question scope. XSRF is the same as a malicious but authorised user from a security perspective, so your answers already cover the concerns to address.

Comment: @Lewis:*"CORS can be handled by the firebase"* - Only if you actively to something, e.g. if you configure it properly. Without doing anything it remains vulnerable against. CORS.

Comment: @Lewis: *"XSRF is the same as a malicious but authorised user"* - No. XSRF is triggered by malicios web sites against fair authenticated users. If you don't do anything to prevent it, it remains vulnerable against XSRF.

Comment: My question is solely about firebase. XSRF needs an authenticated user, which is the same vector needed by my question concerns, so yes these are the same, in the context of my question, because the vector is the same. XSRF is another topic, as is CORS, and I am not asking about them here. Thank you though for bringing them here as it might be useful for other readers. Edit : XSRF is still a concern for my "trusted users", you are right